# How do I populate a cell based on 3 possible values in another cell selected from a drop down list?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

Below is the formula I've tried for D9 in my workbook and I get the error NAME?

=IF(C9=Yes,"PASS",IF(C9=No,"FAIL",IF(C9=Unclear/Insufficient,"QUERY","-")))

Help appreciated

ALSO....

Having solved that, how do I use the Conditional Formatting icon stack to create a green flag for PASS, orange flag for QUERY and red flag for FAIL?

Comment: You selected as the correct answer one that brings the exact solution I gave you before, I don't get it. In fact, the answer you marked was posted after you said "Thanks - can't believe I missed it - was driving me nuts!". I just don't get it.

Comment: I ticked your answer first, so don't know why the other one came up, sorry, will make the change, you deserve the selection....

Comment: Any idea how I can get the Conditional Formatting icon stack to work to color code my values whether PASS, FAIL or QUERY??? As far as I can see, the cell value has to be a number to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I think that isn't possible from a formula; you should use the conditional formating wizard for D9 and set the appropiate rules. If you use the wizard, the cell can be a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use quotes for YES, NO and the other one:

=IF(C9="Yes","PASS",IF(C9="No","FAIL",IF(C9="Unclear/Insufficient","QUERY","-")))

And using ',' instead of ';' as parameter separator seams strange to me, I supose that is because of your regional configuration or something like that.

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I missed it - was driving me nuts!

Comment: I think Filburt editted the message because I didn't see the ";"

Answer (score 1):

Try
=IF(C9="Yes","PASS",IF(C9="No","FAIL",IF(C9="Unclear/Insufficient","QUERY","-")))

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the one I previusly posted?

Comment: Nothing is different but I didnt see the ";" in the users original post and therefore I didn't mention it.